# gridview and 52 buttons want compress button capacity

Tags: android

I have got one simple problem, my app contains 52 buttons but i cant display all buttons. I need suggest have can i solve this trouble the best as I can. 
At the moment i have buttons like that:
http://prntscr.com/482kjw
but this solve is untransparent and i want one button make two functionaly one on click and second on long clik or something that, but i havent got idea how..
and now my question is: I need recommendations for the solution of my problem or some tutorial how to display two images on one button, Gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make a layout of two images in one on a linearLayout with orientation:Horizontal or 
To add two pics on one button, try this

```
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_action_done1"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_done2"
```

and so forth.. this puts two images-(@drawable/ic_action_done1 & @drawable/ic_action_done2)- on one button
and speaking of the functionality of the buttons, from my understanding to your question, you need a click function and a long press function, well you can use one button for to achieve these..

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           }
        });
button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```

maybe it might help you.
SAMPLE OR TUTORIAL ON WHAT YOU ASKED 
The name is button_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/registerButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/checkmark"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:text="@string/register"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="22sp" />
```

button_layout is the xml_file you will inflate..in the link you gave me the button_xml was written programatically in the baseAdapter which was

```
imageView imageView; 
imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
```

you can also do yours programmatically in this way

```
Button button = (Button)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.button_layout, null);
```

it seems you are new in android. so check these sites, it might give you a lucid idea of what i mean..

```
http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html
 http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/
 http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_grid_view.htm
 http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/07/custom-grid-view-example-in-android.html
 http://androidexample.com/Custom_Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=76&aaid=100
http://javatechig.com/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android
```

Comment: i nede one tutorial for   android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_action_done1"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_done2"

Comment: hell .........at the moment is my code from this tutorial ...http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html where i add button